# How to handle a large number of Cron jobs with EJB?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.1

I'm writing a website for uptime monitoring tools with EJB3.1
I need to check websites HTTP response code every one minuet. Therefore, I need to run many cron jobs in parallel in the same time during one minuets.
I'm using timer service now, but the problem is, how many timer service can I make in the code (programmatically) or is it the best solution for this problem? Is there something like threadpooling that we have in normal (JavaSE) application in EJB applications?

Comment: TBH, I'm not sure if EJBs/Java EE are a good choice for such a task.

Comment: '@Schedules' and '@Schedule' would allow you to schedule several timers, unlike the timer service

Comment: The problem is, I can not define thousand of schedules statically and even if I can, It makes no sense to schedule part of code when it's no required (when system just has few records to check). But with something like threadpool it would be more efficient.

Comment: @AlexanderLanger, what do you purpose for the technology? This cron job is just 5% of the code, most of the technology that a website has to have like Storage, administration, reporting, API and ... is very easy and straightforward to create with JavaEE.

Comment: Use standalone programs (or one multi-threaded one) scheduled by a proper scheduler (possibly one that also can take into account long running cron jobs and the like) and feed the results into a message queue that is then processed via JMS in your Java EE environment.  That way you can also distribute the heavy task (thousand of parallel checks) to mutiple machines easily